# Power Query: alternating highlighting based on row values

Tags: excel, powerquery, conditional-formatting

So my column is sorted in ascending order. I want the 000001s to be highlighted the same color and for the 000002s to be highlighted another color. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpoEP.jpg)

What’s the best and most efficient way to go about this?

Comment: Great, feel free to upvote the answer with up arrow if you think it might help someone else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Powerquery does not do formatting / highlighting. If you want, add a column that alternates 0 / 1 and use that to set up a conditional format:

In powerquery

right click ... group by ... use operation all rows

[image]

add column .. index column

Click select index column and standard ... modulo ... 2..

[image]

Click select the arrow atop the grouped column and expand

right click and remove extra columns then file... close and load back to excel...

[image]

use that to set up conditional formatting in excel (image does not match new data, but same theory)

[image]

and copy to all ranges

[image]

Comment: I’m not sure this would work as I want the alternation to occur based on when the value of the the subject column changes. I would want both of the rows that reads “a” to be one color because of its value. Then I’d want the rows that are b to be the alternate color and so forth

Comment: That worked! Do you think there’s a way to make this take into account filtered rows? Like if I filtered for just rows that contained “a” and “c”, would it be possible to have the highlighting be different?

Comment: filter=x. then do the other steps, then potentially merge with the filter<>x data to recombine